# What can we deduce about $k$, given that $i$ is an integer and $k$ is a prime number such that $k|i$ and $k|(i+5)$?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I would need your assistance to solve the following question.

What can you deduce about $k$, given that $i$ is an integer and $k$ is a prime number such that $k|i$ and $k|(i+5)$?

Am I correct to deduce that $k$ is $5$?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. You may be expected to use a couple of steps, first noting that $k$ divides $(i+5)-i$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right.

$k$ divides $i$ i.e. $k|i$

and

$k$ divides $i+5$ i.e. $k|i+5$

$\Rightarrow k|(i+5)-i$

$\Rightarrow k|5$ which implies $k=1$ or $k=5$.

But it is given that $k$ is a prime number.

Hence $k=5$.

Comment: Hi SchrodingersCat, I need help in understanding how to derieve (i+5)-i. Thanks!

Comment: @user292965 Observe that $k|i+5 \Rightarrow i+5=km$ and $k|i \Rightarrow i=kn$ for suitable integers $m,n$.Hence, $k(m-n)=(i+5)-i=5$.  Now $k$ divides L.H.S. i.e. $k(m-n)$. So $k$ must divide R.H.S. i.e. $5$ in order that the above expression is true. Is your doubt resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are. Write $i $ and $i+5$ explicitly as multiples of $k $ and subtract to conclude that $k $ divides 5.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

If $k \mid i$, there exists an integer $m$ such that $km = i$.  If $k \mid (i + 5)$, there exists an integer $n$ such that $kn = i + 5$.  Hence, 
$$5 = i + 5 - i = kn - km = k(m - n)$$
Since the difference of integers is an integer, $m - n$ is an integer.  Thus, $k \mid 5 \implies k = \pm 1, \pm 5$.  Of these values, only $5$ is prime.  Hence, $k = 5$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct to deduce that $k = 5$, assuming that the possibility of negative integers like $k = -5$ has been explicitly or tacitly ruled out.

If $k \mid i$ and $k \mid (i - 5)$, then $k \mid ((i + 5) - i)$ which means $k \mid 5$. The only prime numbers satisfying this are $5$ and $-5$.